# Azure - Making an API App available to a Logic App

Tags: security, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I've created a web application API with a swagger interface that I've deployed as an API App to Azure.

When creating a Logic App I can find my API App but whenever I try to use it I get the following error:

> Failed to fetch swagger. Ensure you have CORS enabled on the endpoint
>   and are calling an HTTPS endpoint.

I'm using the default https url for the API definition in the API App:

https://microsoft-SOME-LONG-MS-INTERNAL-ID.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1

The swagger docs have been provided in my C# web API application through Swashbuckle.

For CORS I've set a single * item.

This didn't seem sufficient for the Logic App to access the API App I then configured Authentication / Authorization for the API App to use Azure Active Directory (express), creating an AD Azure App.

I believe the issue will be one of configuring security which is all pretty new to me in Azure. I'd like to make the API App inaccessible externally, but available to Web Apps and Logic Apps within my Azure subscription.

I've not added any authentication mechanism to the ASP.NET web application itself as I figured the web application would effectively be sitting in a private network on Azure. Perhaps this is a bad assumption and I need to add authentication to allow Azure AD to work?

Any pointers / suggestions?

Comment: Which logicapp version are you using?

Comment: @TusharJ - The logic app was created directly in the portal. I added a new "Logic App (preview)" item. In the properties it says type is "Microsoft.Logic/workflows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to update the Azure SDK for Visual Studio. I had an older version that was deploying a preview Api App which resulted in a "Api app host" type being deployed rather that an "API app" type.

Everything works after the update and I've found some documentation for securing the API App and making it available in the Logic App - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-custom-hosted-api/

Comment: good your problem is resolved this was my speculation also and hence i was asking the version for it. Usually version will be something like "version 2015-08-01-preview" which you could find in the codeview also.